# What to gain from VS2012 when migrating from VS2010 and building WinForms apps?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, migration

We are using VS2010 to build different WinForms apps.

I look at new tool versions regularly, but didn't really have time to check out VS2012 so far, so I am wondering: What would be the advantage of using VS2012 for us over VS2010 when developing WinForms apps.

Are there are really "cool" new features out there for us in VS2012? Or even more importantly any productivity gains?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**#1) Develop for Windows 8**

Visual Studio 2012 contains all the tools you need to develop killer apps for Windows 8, from templates, to designers, to testing, to debugging. Blend now comes with the Visual Studio installation providing rich visual tools for creating Windows store apps using HTML/CSS and XAML. Using these tools, you’ll find everything you need to develop a great app and submit it to the Windows Store.

**#2) Develop for the Web**

Visual Studio 2012 and .NET 4.5 provide the latest advances in ASP.NET including web optimization improvements (minification and bundling), new templates, HTML & CSS editor improvements, page inspector, and new publishing tools. We’ve added new features to support JavaScript development including IntelliSense improvements, a new DOM explorer, and a JavaScript console.

**#3) Develop for Windows Phone 8**

Visual Studio 2012 will provide support for developing Windows Phone 8 applications (both with a Express SKU as well as a freely downloadable plug-in for VS Pro and above). This will come online in the future, once Windows Phone 8 and the developer SDK become available. Some new features to look forward to include native C++ support, the ability to target both Windows Phone 7.x and Windows Phone 8 applications, multi-chassis support, and enterprise publishing. Stay tuned for more info from the Windows Phone team.

**#5) Develop Business Applications**

Visual Studio 2012 contains a variety of tools for developing business applications. SharePoint developers will find new designers for list and content types, new templates for site columns and Silverlight web pages, as well as new options for deploying SharePoint sites. ALM features like performance profiling, unit testing, and IntelliTrace are now available for SharePoint development. Client-side development has been improved as well, with support for JavaScript debugging and IntelliSense.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasonz/archive/2012/08/15/visual-studio-2012-and-net-framework-4-5-released-to-the-web.aspx

If you will be using any of these feature in your apps it is beneficial for you otherwise vs 2010 is already good tool provides great features.